# How to query nested objects from MongoDB using Spring Boot (REST) and TextQuery?

Tags: spring, mongodb, rest, spring-boot

I am writing RESTful API to search MongoDB collection named 'global' by criteria using TextQuery. My problem is that I cannot access nested object fields when doing query.

For example this works:

```
GET localhost:8080/search?criteria=name:'name'
```

And this does not:

```
GET localhost:8080/search?criteria=other.othername:'Other Name'
```

I have MongoDB  json structure (imported from JSON into 'global' collection as whole nested objects)

```
[{
   "name": "Name",
   "desc": "Desc",
   "other" {
     "othername": "Other Name",

    }
 },
 {
   "name": "Name",
   "desc": "Desc",
   "other" {
     "othername": "Other Name",

    }
 }
]
```

And classes (with getters & setters & etc):

```
@Document(collection="global")
public class Global{
  @TextIndexed
  String name;
  @TextIndexed
  String desc;
  Other other;
  ...
}


public class Other{
  String othername;
  ...
}
```

My controller has method

```
@GetMapping("/search")
 public Iterable<Global> getByCriteria(@RequestParam("criteria") String criteria) {
...
}
```

And I am trying to write text search with

```
public Iterable<Global> findByCriteria(String criteria) {
        TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matching(criteria);
        TextQuery query = TextQuery.queryText(criteria);
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, Global.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `@TextIndexed` to your `other` field.

```
public class Global{
  @TextIndexed
  String name;
  @TextIndexed
  String desc;
  @TextIndexed
  Other other;
  ...
}
```

**Note:** All nested object fields are searchable

or you may add `@TextIndexed` for each nested object field:

```
public class Other {
  @TextIndexed
  String othername;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this works. Can you suggest me how to pass more parametes in criteria? Something like: GET localhost:8080/search?criteria=name:'name',other.othername:'Other Name'